# Change hover-text of Telerik MVC grid save icon

Tags: telerik, tooltip, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik MVC (not Kendo) grid that uses the [default Ajax binding for editing](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-editing-ajax-editing.html). For some unfathomable reason, when editing a row, the Save and Cancel buttons sport a tooltip of "Edit". I have not found where to define the Title text for the Save or Cancel buttons, only for the Edit and Delete buttons:

```
commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid-edit-button" }).ImageHtmlAttributes(new { @alt = "Edit", @title = "Edit" });
commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid-delete-button" }).ImageHtmlAttributes(new { @alt = "Delete", @title = "Delete" });
```

[image: Incorrect tooltip when mouse is hovering over it]

This is code that I copied from another section of the project (unfortunately, written by someone who has since left the company) and it works correctly there. I have had no luck asking Telerik for help, as the MVC libraries are not their most current offerings (but I must use them for legacy reasons).

Does anyone know how to force the tool-tip text to the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be better solutions, but I wound up fixing it through some Javascript trickery (this is what is used by the other instances of this grid. I'd missed it because I had custom edit code for handling the dropdown boxes):

In the grid definition:

```
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBound("defaultGridDataBound").OnEdit("defaultGridEdit"))
```

And then:

```
function defaultGridEdit(e) {
    var $form = $(e.form);
    if (e.mode == "insert") {
        $form.find(".t-grid-insert .t-insert").attr("title", "Save");
        $form.find(".t-grid-insert .t-insert").attr("alt", "Save");
    }
    else {
        $form.find(".t-grid-update .t-update").attr("title", "Save");
        $form.find(".t-grid-update .t-update").attr("alt", "Save");
    }

    $form.find(".t-grid-cancel .t-cancel").attr("title", "Cancel");
    $form.find(".t-grid-cancel .t-cancel").attr("alt", "Cancel");
}
```